# Send X-CSRF Token to a Django server using XHTTP Request or jQuery Ajax

Tags: django, ajax, django-csrf

I've been trying to make a POST to my Django application via XHTTP Request and jQuery with no correct result at all.

The fact is that the Django app is on one of my subdomains, and the web app is in another, not being part of the Django app, just only a separated app.

I've been reading the docs, but none of this works.

All of my subdomains are in the ALLOWED HOSTS list and in the CORS ORIGIN WHITELIST, and the petition works correctly with GET, but POST returns me a Forbidden 403 error telling CSRF Cookie not found.

This is the code of my petition.

```
var petition = new XMLHttpRequest();
petition.open('POST','http://localhost:8000/login/',true);
petition.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken",sessionStorage["csrf_token"]);
petition.send()
```

I already have stored the CSRF cookie in the session storage with this function.

```
function storeCSRFToken(){
    var token;
    $.ajax({
        url : 'http://localhost:8000/token',
        type: "GET",
        dataType : "json",
        success: function( data ){
            token = data.csrf_token;
            sessionStorage['csrf_token'] = token;
        }
    });
}
```

Any clue of what is going wrong?

Comment: try to set [CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN) in your django project and check if it is working

Comment: I have set this to True and I still getting the same error `Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /login/
[17/Feb/2020 09:07:14] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2864`

Comment: it should be a string (your domain name), read the documentation.

Comment: My fault, already have tried this and still got the same error.
I even have tried in localhost but none of this works.